'70s movie about college guys who create a brothel as a school "study"
This was a movie I saw years ago and don't remember the name.
It was about several college students who decided to do a "sex study" for a class. They paid girls to have sex with men from the community, all as part of the "study." The men would fill out a questionnaire about the experience. As time went on, it grew into a large production with lots of girls and even nuns delivering food and stuff to the hotel they were using. Of course, they made a ton of money, but they eventually ended up in court and lost everything. 

Welcome to Movies & TV, and thanks for your question! I hope we can help you find an answer. To that end, you have some really good detail about the plot. And thanks for putting in the decade the movie came out! Is there any chance you might also remember some other non-plot-related details? (e.g. Language and/or country of origin? Any familiar names/faces in the cast? Ans so on. If you can remember any of these extra details, feel free to click "edit" on your question to add them in.)
